# Error 1001 : DNS resolution error for my website after removing domain from Cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare

I have a website that is hosted in AWS. It was pointing through Cloudflare for the last one year and one month back I removed that traffic (deleted the domain from Cloudflare account). Before two days, my site is not working, it is showing Error 1001 : DNS resolution error.

When I try to check [whoishosting](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/?q=schoolvoice.com), I am getting proper response.

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Looks like your website is up to me. In Chrome dev tools I can see that the resources are loading from the IP that your domain A record points to. Have you flushed your DNS cache?

Comment: Thanks @JorgRoper, I have flushed the DNS Cache, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: If you do a `nslookup schoolvoice.com` on your computer, does it return the right IP? If so, suggest it may be to do with your computer? If not, update your DNS server to be something more reliable - eg Google's DNS. https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/schoolvoice.com - shows the A records have replicated around the world....

Comment: I am getting Non-authoritative answer: 
Name: schoolvoice.com
Address: 104.X.X.X

That IP is of Cloudflare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your DNS is returning the wrong IP address, that is the old IP address for your website. Given WhatsmyDNS (in my comment above - ie https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/schoolvoice.com) shows that DNS records around the world are all set with the new IP, its something to do with your local computer/network not seeing the new IP address. As you've already flushed the DNS cache on your computer and that hasn't fixed it, I suggest updating the DNS servers you use.

You can do this at a computer level by following the guide here (for windows - sorry not sure what OS you are using on your computer): https://www.teamknowhow.com/kit-guide/computing/laptops/dell/inspiron-13-5000/how-to-change-your-dns-settings-windows-10 - I'd suggest using Google DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (reference: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

You can test the results that using Google DNS will produce. This is instructions for Windows but you can do similar on other OSs:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Type `nslookup` -> enter
3. Type `server 8.8.8.8` -> enter (this tells nslookup to use that server, ie google's DNS server for this query)
4. Type `schoolvoice.com` -> enter. This should show you the latest IP for the A record for that domain

(reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup )

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jorg Roper.
But When I am trying from my local network I am unable to connect. 
The solution is I need to flush the DNS from our local server. For that I need to contact server team, I guess.

Comment: Yep, if you can't connect and continue to see the same issue with outdated DNS results, I'd talk to your server team.

Comment: Thanks for all your help